# Mocha for node js app in Visual Studio 2019 is not showing Tests in Test Explorer when reference or require another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, visual-studio-2019

I am using node js in VS 2019.  I want to try Mocha as the test platform so I have gone through and installed that and got it working in a basic sense.  I have a simple calculator node js file (calc.js).

I have another file that has basic hello world tests (basictest.js).  If I do NOT put in the "require" line for Calc.js, then these tests (Test 1 and Test 2) are discovered by VS 2019 test explorer and are listed.

However, I need the require line to access the calculator app, so when I put the require line `var mycalc = require('./Scripts/Calc.js');` in there, the tests are NOT discovered.  The same thing happens if I try a reference `path=..` to it. I am new to node js so I could be missing something seemingly obvious as well when referencing functions in another js file.

**basictest.js:**

```
'use strict';

var assert = require('assert');
var mycalc = require('./Scripts/Calc.js');

describe('Test Suite 1', function () {
it('Test 1', function () {
    assert.ok(true, "This shouldn't fail");
});

it('Test 2', function () {
    assert.ok(1 === 1, "This shouldn't fail");
    assert.ok(false, "This should fail");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ... I figured it out after hours of searching online and had no success.

This line here wasn't completely correct:
   var mycalc = require('./Scripts/Calc.js');

For some reason js finds the calc.js file and test file.  However, the test explorer wasn't able to discover the tests.  The reason is a simple "."  My guess is that ./Scripts/ puts current working directory in the Scripts directory and VS is unable to find the tests.  Just adding a second "." moves it back a directory so the Tests can be found.

Correct code:
   var mycalc = require('../Scripts/Calc.js');